# usenet server uses more bandwidth then I can measure

Tags: networking, internet, bandwidth, usenet, speedtest

So here's the situation. I just started using usenet (server Newshosting), and I am on a bit of a limited bandwidth local network so I've been trying to figure out how much bandwidth I'm actually using. So, I run speedtest.net, tells me I'm around 4.5 Mbps-5.0 Mbps. I turn on my usenet client (SABnzbd), and it says the download speed is ~500 kbps. I run speedtest again, and my download speed drops to around ~0.5 Mbps.

So the math doesn't add up.

This is reproduceable, and I'm experimented with limited the bandwidth of the client to ~100 kbps, which gets me around 3.0 Mbps, so it's consistent with not downloading as fast as it claims.

Is there just a lot of overhead bandwidth involved in these usenet servers? Is there a specific reason this is happening? Can I do anything about it? Obviously, I'd like

(speedtest-no-usenet)=(speedtest-with-usenet)+(usenet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look more carefully. Your download speed isn't "500 **kbps**", it's "500 **KB/s**". The math does add up if you add numbers with the same units.

500 KB/s = 4.1 Mbps.

There are 1,024 bytes in a kilobyte. There are 8 bits in a byte.

Comment: Foolish me thinking b and B are the same. Perfect answer to an apparently dumb question. Thanks!